# Speeding up array search, Possibly 2D Collection if that is possible?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I need some help speeding up the current code I am running.

To start, I have a large `data` sheet That has roughly 180,000 lines, and a `unique` sheet that has only the unique values from that large list that is roughly 9000 lines so it will currently take too long to make this code feasible. The Current `i` and `j` values are just place holders to test if the code was working.

I had the idea to create a collection to store the data so that once it was matched, it could then be deleted from the collection so it was not needed to be checked again later for another value in the `uniqueArray()`.

Is a collection possible since i need to check for 3 conditions before adding the value of the 4th cell?

I really appreciate any help or advice since i have really only been programming in VBA for a few weeks here and there.

```
Sub getHours(uniqueArray() As Variant, Lastrow As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer, lastData As Long
    Dim tempTerms As Integer
    Dim OpenForms

    Sheets("Data").Select
    lastData = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 1 To Lastrow
        uniqueArray(i, 2) = 0
    Next i
    i = 0

    For i = 1 To 10 'Lastrow

        tempTerms = 0
        tempProj = uniqueArray(i, 1)

        If i Mod 30 = 0 Then
            openform = DoEvents
        End If

        For j = 2 To 10000  'lastData
            If tempProj = Cells(j, 10).Value _
            And Cells(j, 5).Value = 55 Then
                tempTerms = tempTerms + Cells(j, 8).Value
            End If
        Next j

    uniqueArray(i, 2) = tempTerms
    Application.StatusBar = i

    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: You're iterating cells on the active worksheet, reading ~300,000 values from the worksheet. That is what's slowing your code down. Don't read from cells in a loop. Copy the range to an array and iterate the array instead. Updating the status bar & repainting the UI for every `i` is also considerably slowing down execution.

Comment: Copy the cell range values into a 2d array first and do your tests against that instead of actual cells. Turn off events, calculation, screen updates but remember to enable them again after.

Comment: @CLR since no writes are being made, disabling events, calculations and screen updates is going to have a negligible effect. Single biggest issue is reading cell values *from the worksheet* in a loop.

Comment: @Mat'sMug if I may ask, how come it it is going through about 300,000 lines?

Comment: @CLR I added the `unique` values to an array, are you suggesting i also move the needed `data` cells into another array to speed it up? secondly, Is there a way to assign the values without looping through each column?

Comment: Truth is, it's likely not. I simply took 10000 iterations of `j` times 10 iterations of `i` times 3 (once for `Cells(j, 10)`, once for `Cells(j, 5)` and once for `Cells(j, 8)`). But the `Cells(j, 8)` read is conditional, but the `And` is badly formed and will not work as intended as far as I can see. You have `If tempProj = Cells(j, 10).Value And Cells(j, 5).Value = 55 Then` but likely intended to have `If tempProj = Cells(j, 10).Value = 55 And Cells(j, 5).Value = 55 Then` - the first part of your Boolean expression will evaluate to a constant expression `True` if `Cells(j, 10).Value <> 0`

Comment: To load an array with cell values you ought to declare the array and then you need to just `ArrayName = RangeToCopy.Value` to load the values to the array.

Comment: @Mat'sMug actually the `IF` statement is supposed to check if `tempProj` is equal the the value in cell `J10`, if that is true, then check to see if `J5` is equal to 55. Is that how this is currently done or did I mess up and incorrectly format this statement. Also, How come it will always evaluate to a constant expression? Sorry for asking so many questions, I am trying to understand VBA better.

Comment: `If foo And bar = 42` is not the same as `If foo = 42 And bar = 42`. In your code `If Cells(j, 10).Value` is evaluated as a Boolean expression, the result of which is used as the left-hand operand of the `And` logical operator that follows. Hence, if the expression was meant to be true when both `(j,10)` and `(j,5)` are `55`, you have a bug, because your condition evaluates to true when `(j,10)` is non-zero and `(j,5)` is `55`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug so then should I separate it into two different `If` loops so then i can get `if tempProj = Cells(j,10).value` as the first conditional statement for the first loop and then `If cells(j,5).value = 55` for the second one?

Comment: You'll possibly shave a few milliseconds splitting it into two different `If` blocks (because the 2nd one will only evaluate if the 1st one is true), but the point was that you need a boolean expression that does what you intend it to do. I'm pointing out a logical bug in your code, not a performance micro-optimization. If you want performance start with dumping your data into an array and iterate the array instead of the worksheet.

Comment: @Mat'sMug how can I fix this logical bug? both cells `J10` and `J5` are independent of each other and need to be matched to a specific value. I apologize if something is going over my head.

Comment: 3rd and last time: `If tempProj = Cells(j, 10).Value = 55 And Cells(j, 5).Value = 55 Then`

Comment: @Mat'sMug sorry, but I don't want `tempProj = 55` It will be a project number such as 4200-12. I only want cell J5 to match a value of 55

Comment: Whatever. Read what your code is doing with `Cells(j, 10).Value` in that condition. Then read it again. Do you *intend* `If Cells(j, 10).Value` to evaluate to `True` for any non-zero value? If so, then your code is unclear and needs to be more explicit because the way it's written it has all the looks of a logical bug.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I did put it in separate loops and It substantially increase the speed of it, probably because it fixes this bug. Does `if cells(j, 10).value` always evaluate true no matter what is after the `=` sign?

Comment: What does `If "4200-12"` evaluate to?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I agree that would definitely resolve to `true`, but would it not be evaluated as `if "4200-12" = Cells(j, 10).value`?

Comment: I give up. Good luck!

Comment: @Mat'sMug I am not trying to be a pester and I apologize, but does the = sign get disregarded and it only evaluates the `4200-12` and see that as tru and move on?

Comment: F9 to set a breakpoint, F8 to step through

Comment: My apologies, I've misread the conditional and glossed over the `tempProj` (an undeclared variable?) operand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load 180K rows into array, MUST sort 180K array, then binary search against that sorted array.

Use memo of matched row for each iteration of outer loop, then stop testing for conditions on inner loop once matching is finished. Go easy on the interface updates.

Doevents on each outer iteration is enuff to get by. Just a dump of adequate functions below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getHours()
  Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
  arr1 = Sheet1.Range("A2:B9001").Value2
  arr2 = Sheet2.Range("A2:J180001").Value2  'whatever your range is

  QuickSort1 arr2, 10   'sorting data on column 10 as you had it.

  Dim i As Long, j As Long, tempSum As Long

  For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        tempSum = 0

        Dim retArr As Variant
        retArr = wsArrayBinaryLookup(arr1(i, 1), arr2, 10, 10, False)
        If Not IsError(retArr(0)) Then
        If arr1(i, 1) = retArr(0) Then
              Dim matchRow As Long
              matchRow = retArr(1)
              'Go through from matched row till stop matching
              Do
                    If arr2(matchRow, 10) <> arr1(i, 1) Then Exit Do
                    If arr2(matchRow, 5) = 55 Then
                          tempSum = tempSum + arr2(matchRow, 8)
                    End If
                    matchRow = matchRow + 1
              Loop While matchRow <= UBound(arr2)
        End If
        End If
        arr1(i, 2) = tempSum
        DoEvents
  Next i

  Sheet1.Range("A2:B9001").Value2 = arr1
End Sub

Public Sub QuickSort1( _
                       ByRef pvarArray As Variant, _
                       ByVal colToSortBy, _
                       Optional ByVal plngLeft As Long, _
                       Optional ByVal plngRight As Long)
  Dim lngFirst As Long
  Dim lngLast As Long
  Dim varMid As Variant
  Dim varSwap As Variant

  If plngRight = 0 Then
        plngLeft = LBound(pvarArray)
        plngRight = UBound(pvarArray)
  End If

  lngFirst = plngLeft
  lngLast = plngRight
  varMid = pvarArray((plngLeft + plngRight) \ 2, colToSortBy)

  Do
        Do While pvarArray(lngFirst, colToSortBy) < varMid And lngFirst < plngRight
              lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
        Loop

        Do While varMid < pvarArray(lngLast, colToSortBy) And lngLast > plngLeft
              lngLast = lngLast - 1
        Loop

        Dim arrColumn As Long
        If lngFirst <= lngLast Then
              For arrColumn = 1 To UBound(pvarArray, 2)
                    varSwap = pvarArray(lngFirst, arrColumn)
                    pvarArray(lngFirst, arrColumn) = pvarArray(lngLast, arrColumn)
                    pvarArray(lngLast, arrColumn) = varSwap
              Next arrColumn
              lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
              lngLast = lngLast - 1
        End If

  Loop Until lngFirst > lngLast

  If plngLeft < lngLast Then QuickSort1 pvarArray, colToSortBy, plngLeft, lngLast
  If lngFirst < plngRight Then QuickSort1 pvarArray, colToSortBy, lngFirst, plngRight
End Sub

Public Function wsArrayBinaryLookup( _
               ByVal val As Variant, _
               arr As Variant, _
               ByVal searchCol As Long, _
               ByVal returnCol As Long, _
               Optional exactMatch As Boolean = True) As Variant

  Dim a As Long, z As Long, curr As Long
  Dim retArr(0 To 1) As Variant

  retArr(0) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
  retArr(1) = 0
  wsArrayBinaryLookup = retArr
  a = LBound(arr)
  z = UBound(arr)


  If compare(arr(a, searchCol), val) = 1 Then
        Exit Function
  End If

  If compare(arr(a, searchCol), val) = 0 Then
        retArr(0) = arr(a, returnCol)
        retArr(1) = a
        wsArrayBinaryLookup = retArr
        Exit Function
  End If

  If compare(arr(z, searchCol), val) = -1 Then
        Exit Function
  End If

  While z - a > 1
        curr = Round((CLng(a) + CLng(z)) / 2, 0)
        If compare(arr(curr, searchCol), val) = 0 Then
              z = curr
              retArr(0) = arr(curr, returnCol)
              retArr(1) = curr
              wsArrayBinaryLookup = retArr
        End If

        If compare(arr(curr, searchCol), val) = -1 Then
              a = curr
        Else
              z = curr
        End If
  Wend

  If compare(arr(z, searchCol), val) = 0 Then
        retArr(0) = arr(z, returnCol)
        retArr(1) = z
        wsArrayBinaryLookup = retArr
  Else
        If Not exactMatch Then
              retArr(0) = arr(a, returnCol)
              retArr(1) = a
              wsArrayBinaryLookup = retArr
        End If
  End If


End Function
Public Function compare(ByVal x As Variant, ByVal y As Variant) As Long

  If IsNumeric(x) And IsNumeric(y) Then
        Select Case x - y
              Case Is = 0
                    compare = 0
              Case Is > 0
                    compare = 1
              Case Is < 0
                    compare = -1
        End Select
  Else
        If TypeName(x) = "String" And TypeName(y) = "String" Then
              compare = StrComp(x, y, vbTextCompare)
        End If
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Should take about 5 seconds to run

Comment: Thank you very much for all this code. Definitely a better way to go about it and for for some reason I didn't even think to use binary search, even though I have used it a little bit in the past. Right now it seems to be giving me a `Type Mismatch` on the line with `if arr1(i,1) = retArr(0) Then` line.

Comment: @Macromark Also, When you are using `Quicksort` to sort column 10, are you only sorting column 10, or sorting all with respect to column 10?

Comment: It is sorting the whole array with respect to column 10. I have tinkered with the code a bit, so perhaps some Lbound(arr) rather than 1. Also where type mismatch, check for errors (use IsError function on the retArr(0) variable). Sorry this was just a bit of amended code I threw together from some stock code. The binaryLookUp function can give an error in retArr(0) if not found, so test for that

Comment: from looking at it, and i'm sure I could be missing something, But it appears that when the `wsArrayBinaryLookup` function is first called, it will do `if compare(arr(a, searchCol), val) = 1` and then exit function right away. So at this point the `retArr(0) = CVErr(xlErrNa)` is true. Is this the problem?

Comment: That simply tests if the first value is 'larger' than the search item. Any chance this is the case...

Comment: i did find one point where the `uniqueArray` was put in place for the `data` array. I am currently stepping through it to find errors along with working it in with other modules of my code. I will message you if I find any errors I can't resolve by myself.

Comment: Do you have an idea why I am getting a `Type mismatch` when it is trying to do `tempSum = tempSum + arr2(matchRow, 8)` even if the value in that cell is just 0? It is saying the `sheetdata(matchRow, 8) = NULL`

Comment: Sorry just got time for this. Yes you were correct. Good debugging on your part. See edit

Comment: I put an If block around the other one in the sub getHours(testing for errors). Also I missed out the first assignment of wsBinaryLookUp's return value in that function as you were hinting...

Comment: This has decreased the run time of 3000 of the unique values from a long time down to 5 seconds (including some other small modules i have not shown here). Do you why it would be possible for this to get hung up to on a specific cell for a `type mismatch` because `sheetdata(matchRow, 8) = NULL` even though the cell is equal to 0? Ive tried to step through it and it gets hung up on the same cell for some reason.

EDIT: just realized the row i am looking at is not the same as the row it is looking at because it is looking at the sorted list. I will have to do some more detective work

Comment: @macromac turns out some data has `NULL` within the actual data itself. This is an internal problem that will have to be fixed later i guess. Thank you very much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Sub getHours(uniqueArray() As Variant, Lastrow As Integer)
> ```

The procedure is implicily `Public`, and the parameters are implicitly passed `ByRef`. As a maintainer I would expect a method named `getHours` to *get* me the "hours", whatever that is - but a `Sub` procedure doesn't *return* anything to its callers, like a `Function` does. Hence the name is misleading. Procedures *do* something, they need a descriptive name that says what it does, ...and then the code needs to do what the name says.

Consistency is also important: you have a `camelCase` public procedure name, and then mixed-up `camelCase` and `PascalCase` parameter names. Stick to `PascalCase` for module members, and use `camelCase` for locals/parameters. Or whatever - just be *consistent* about it.

`LastRow` being an `Integer` raises a flag. `Integer` is a 16-bit signed integer type, making its maximum value 32,767, which will cause problems when you try to assign it to 32,768 or higher. Use a `Long` instead - a 32-bit signed integer type much more appropriate for general-purpose integer values - *especially* for something like a "row number", which can be well above 100K in Excel.

> ```
> Dim i As Integer, lastData As Long
> ```

`i` should be a `Long`, and `lastData` is assigned, but never referred to - remove it and its assignment. Speaking of which...

```
Sheets("Data").Select
lastData = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

Don't `.Select` worksheets. Use a `Worksheet` object instead:

```
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
```

Note that `Range`, unqualified with a `Worksheet` object, implicitly refers to whatever worksheet is active, in whatever workbook is active. Unless you're in a worksheet module's code-behind - in which case it refers to that worksheet. If you mean to do that, be explicit and do `Me.Range` instead. If not, then properly qualify `Range` and `Cells` calls with a `Worksheet` object.

Then use it:

```
lastData = dataSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

Some more integers:

> ```
> Dim tempTerms As Integer
> ```

Again, no reason to use a 16-bit integer type, declare `As Long`.

> ```
> Dim OpenForms
> ```

What the heck does this procedure needs to know the number of open forms for? It doesn't. Remove it.

> ```
> openform = DoEvents
> ```

You're assigning to `openform`, but you declared `OpenForms`. If your code compiles and runs, it means you haven't specified `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. Do it. That will prevent VBA from happily compiling typos, and will force you to declare every variable you use. Here `OpenForms` is left unused, and `openform` is an undeclared `Variant` declared on-the-fly by the VBA run-time.

To be honest I didn't even know `DoEvents` returned anything - it returning the number of open forms strikes me as a giant WTF. Anyway, here's how I've always seen it used:

```
DoEvents
```

That's all! Yes, this discards the returned value. But who cares about the number of opened forms in the first place?

`tempProj` isn't declared. Declare it. `j` isn't declared. Declare it.

---

Reading a cell's value is dangerous. Cells contain a `Variant`, so whenever you read a cell's value into a `String` or `Long` or whatever typed variable, you are making VBA perform an implicit type conversion - a conversion that isn't always possible.

This will eventually break - or come back and bite you in this or another project:

> ```
> If tempProj = Cells(j, 10).Value _
> And Cells(j, 5).Value = 55 Then
>     tempTerms = tempTerms + Cells(j, 8).Value
> End If
> ```

You need to be sure the cell doesn't contain an error value before you can do that.

```
If IsError(Cells(j, 10).Value) Or IsError(Cells(j, 5).Value) Or IsError(Cells(j, 8).Value) Then
    MsgBox "Row " & j & " contains an error value in column 5, 8, or 10."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

---

#### Ok, so what about performance?

- Avoid `Variant` when a better type exists.
- Avoid undeclared variables; they're always `Variant`. Use `Option Explicit`.
- Avoid implicit type conversions.
- Avoid `Select` and `Activate`.
- Avoid `DoEvents`.
- Avoid updating the UI (status bar, etc.).
- Avoid accessing worksheet cells in a loop.

Read the worksheet's data into a variant array:

```
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

Dim sheetData As Variant
sheetData = dataSheet.Range("A1:J" & lastData).Value
```

Now `sheetData` is a 2D array that contains every single value in the specified range - all copied in-memory in a split-second.

So the `j` loop becomes something like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
Dim j As Long
For j = 2 To lastData
    If tempProj = sheetData(j, 10) And sheetData(j, 5) = 55 Then
        tempTerms = tempTerms + sheetData(j, 8)
    End If
Next j
```

Now I see what you're doing. `uniqueArray` is your return value! Hard to tell by just looking at the method's signature - naming it `result` or better, `outHoursPerTerm`, would go a long way into making the code easier to understand at a glance.

Consider setting the `Application.Cursor` to a hourglass and set it back to default once done - possibly also setting the status bar to "Please wait..." or something similar. *If* the thing takes longer than 5-8 seconds, *then* consider updating the status bar for every couple iterations of the outer loop, but note that doing that will make the procedure considerably slower.

Toggling calculation, worksheet events, screen updating and whatnot, isn't going to help here - you're not writing anywhere, only reading. Work off an in-memory 2D array and you should see considerable performance improvements.

---

This answer purposely reads like a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) answer. Questions about improving working code (performance, readability, etc.) are usually a better fit on CR. Consider asking on CR next time you need help improving your working code - as you can see a CR answer covers much more ground than a typical SO answer.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Not tested, written in the answer box. Might need to transpose rows into columns.</sub>

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the in depth comments about this code, but do you know why I would have a `subscript out of range` on the `Set dataSheet = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("data")` line?

Comment: That would be because there is no worksheet named "data" in `ThisWorkbook`. Use the `Workbook` object that contains that sheet, I assumed `ThisWorkbook` (the book containing the executing code) was also the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: This has definitely made this program much faster, It does seems slow still so I may have to think of another approach to it.

Comment: If your code works, just slow, put it up on [codereview.se]. Describe its purpose, *present* it to reviewers - and you'll get tips to speed it up and clean it up.

Comment: @BlakeLindeman if at the end of the day you're computing a scalar value from a number of cells, ...looks like a `SUMIF` function could do it. If you absolutely need this done in VBA, you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf. Should be *a notch* faster ;-)

Comment: was doing some searching on "Can a collection be 2d or multi dimensional" and stumbled on this question.  The second part of the quest does not seem to be answered.  Just a bunch of different ways of doing what the person is trying to achieve.  I could not find an answer to if collections can be 2D?  all the examples I find they are 1D.  Can you say if 2D or more is possible?

Comment: @ForwardEd you will not find an answer to that question, because collections aren't arrays, they're not "dimensioned". A collection is a data structure that lets you add/remove elements, iterate them, and access them by index or by key. What the collection items are is entirely up to you (make each element a 5D array if you like), but keep in mind that collections work best with objects and `For Each` loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually use for speeding:

```
Public Sub OnEnd()    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False        
    Application.StatusBar = False        
End Sub

Public Sub OnStart()        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False        
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView    
End Sub

Sub getHours(uniqueArray() As Variant, Lastrow As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer, lastData As Long
    Dim tempTerms As Integer
    Dim OpenForms

    call OnStart
    code ...

    Next i

    call OnEnd

End Sub
```

The `ScreenUpdating = False` does about 90% of the job, the rest is there just to make sure it runs as expected.

**Edit:**
Theoretically, if you change `Dim tempTerms As Integer` to `Long` it should be faster. And probably it is better to define `OpenForms` as something.

Comment: Not a silver bullet. OP isn't writing to any cell, they're only reading. No calculation, worksheet events, or anything of the sort is slowing it down - the effect is going to be negligible.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - at least `Sheets("Data").Select` is going to be influenced. :) And to be honest, I read `And Cells(j, 5).Value = 55 Then` without the `And` part :)

Comment: @Vityata I think most of the slowness is coming from searching all 180,000 lines 9000 separate times lol. But that did speed it up but by about 1 second out of 30 seconds for my test case of partial `unique` and `data` rows.

Comment: 180K * 9K is quite a bit, @BlakeLindeman. Probably you may read something about DP and use it in your example - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming or try to eliminate `openform = DoEvents` if possible.

Comment: @Vityata I will definitely look into that, Do you have any ideas where I could speed this up at all?

Comment: @BlakeLindeman - I don't know what the events you are using. But probably my part of the code eliminates them, thus make a double check whether they are actually happening.